# loop through a collection of objects c#

Tags: c#, reflection

I am passing an object as a parameter to my function and that object contains a  list of objects of type `FeatureItemInfo`.

`FeatureItemInfo` is a class with the following properties:

```
 Name, Value , Type , DisplayOrder, Column
```

I want to loop through the list  and display the properties of each `<FeatureItemInfo>`  object .

here is what i could come up with so far. But I am unable to get the values of the featureIteminfo.

Here is my function:

```
 public static TagBuilder BuildHtml(StringBuilder  output, object model)
    {
     if (model != null)
     {
         foreach (var indexedItem in model.GetType().GetProperties().Select((p, i) => new { item = p, Index = i }))
         {
             var Colval = (int)indexedItem.item.GetType().GetProperty("Column").GetValue(indexedItem.item, null);
......
         }

      }
    }
```

Comment: As Cyborg says, you've already got the property in the indexedItem.item variable.  If you invoke `GetType()` on that, you'll just end up with `typeof(PropertyInfo)`, which has no "Column" property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be:

```
 (int)indexedItem.item.GetValue(model, null);
```

Your `item` property **IS** the [`PropertyInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.aspx) object. You call [`GetValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx) on it, passing an instance of the class, to get the value of that property.

```
indexedItem.item.GetType().GetProperty("Column")
```

The above code will look for the property "Column" on the `PropertyInfo` object (hint: `PropertyInfo` does not have a "Column" property).

---

**Update:** Based on your comments below, `model` is actually a collection of objects. If that's the case, you should probably make that a bit more explicit in your function signature:

```
public static TagBuilder BuildHtml( StringBuilder output, IEnumerable model )
```

Now, let's take a look at your loop:

```
foreach (var indexedItem in model.GetType().GetProperties().Select((p, i) => new { item = p, Index = i }))
```

What this is actually doing:

```
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> l_properties = model.GetType().GetProperties();
var l_customObjects = l_properties.Select( 
        (p, i) =>
            new { 
                item = p, /* This is the PropertyInfo object */
                Index = i /* This is the index of the PropertyInfo 
                             object within l_properties */
            }
    )
foreach ( var indexedItem in l_customObjects )
{
    // ...
}
```

This is getting a list of properties from the model object and then iterating over those properties (or, rather, an anonymous objects wrapping those properties).

I think what you are actually looking for is something more like this:

```
// This will iterate over the objects within your model
foreach( object l_item in model )
{
    // This will discover the properties for each item in your model:
    var l_itemProperties = l_item.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach ( PropertyInfo l_itemProperty in l_itemProperties )
    {
        var l_propertyName = l_itemProperty.Name;
        var l_propertyValue = l_itemProperty.GetValue( l_item, null );
    }

    // ...OR...

    // This will get a specific property value for the current item:
    var l_columnValue = ((dynamic) l_item).Column;
    // ... of course, this will fail at run-time if your item does not
    // have a Column property, unlike the foreach loop above which will
    // simply process all properties, whatever their names
}
```

Comment: I get the error Object does not match target type  @  indexedItem.item.GetType().GetProperty("Column")

Comment: @BumbleBee - I made a mistake. Should be `GetValue(model, null)`, not `GetValue(indexedItem.item, null)`.

Comment: I am confused. u mean var Colval = (int)indexedItem.item.GetType().GetProperty("Column").GetValue(indexedItem.item, null);                                                    should be                                                          var Colval = (int)indexedItem.item.GetType().GetProperty("Column").GetValue(model, null);

Comment: @BumbleBee No....... I mean what I have above. `var Colval = (int)indexedItem.item.GetValue(model, null);` You do not want `.GetType().GetProperty("Column")` - you already have a reference to the property via your `indexItem.item` property. All you need to do now is get a value for that property from a specific instance of that class. You should read up on reflection before you try to use it: [Reflection in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx)

Comment: @BumbleBee - This is all assuming that `model` is just a single object. If it is a list of objects (`List<Stats.Models.FeatureItemInfo>`) then you will need to extract a single item from that list before attempting to get the value for that property.

Comment: s u r right. It is a list of objects. that's where i am getting lost.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach considered is to use [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741.aspx) which simply get the property directly without reflection:

```
public static TagBuilder BuildHtml(StringBuilder  output, object model)
{
    if (model != null)
    {
        var Colval = ((dynamic)model).Column;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool. I didn't realize that C# had added the ability to skip compile-time type checking via [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. I am getting the following error: 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Stats.Models.FeatureItemInfo>' does not contain a definition for 'Column'

Comment: @BumbleBee - Sounds like your `model` is actually a collection of models rather than a single instance of a model.

Comment: Now i get RuntimeBinderException. 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo' does not contain a definition for 'Column'